# MAUI custom view with data binding

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, maui

I am most likely missing something here or not really understanding how MVVM and Data Binding works, so sorry if I'm asking an obvious question. My team and I are rewriting our app from Xamarin Forms to MAUI.

We have couple of ContentView pages in our old Xamarin app. We then use those content views in xaml to switch between them using a drop down list and just use isVisible property on each of them to display them one at a time. This needs to be like this. Code goes something like this:

```
<StackLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
             HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
             IsVisible="{Binding IsSearchResultsVisible}">
                <controlOne:ViewOne
                            IsVisible="{Binding IsCurrentlyViewingViewOne" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" />
                <ControlTwo:ViewTwo
                            IsVisible="{Binding IsCurrentlyViewingViewTwo" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" />
```

Now this worked in Xamarin app, but now in MAUI it won't work because, if I understood correctly in order to have my viewmodel and view bind I need to inject ViewModel in the code behind of that view:

```
public partial class ViewOne : ContentView
{
    public ViewOne(ViewOneViewModel vm)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = vm; //The important part
    }
    
}
```

Now this is where my question is: **How do I do this without getting a "Type 'ViewOne' is not usable as an object element because it is not public or does not define a public parameterless constructor or a type converter" in a first code?**

Error is there because in xaml control is expected to take no parameters for it's constructor but in code behind it has to take ViewModel object as a parameter. I know I can create another constructor without parameters, but then I won't have databinding to my ViewModel. Can I somehow pass ViewModel in xaml part of the code or am I completely misunderstanding how this is supposed to be done?

Comment: Why does your ContentView require its own ViewModel? It's not a very common thing to do.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Binding not working on custom BindableProperty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73691579/binding-not-working-on-custom-bindableproperty)

Comment: Apart from my previous question: Where should the ViewOneViewModel come from in your specific case? Do you need to inject it or can it be created on-the-fly (as is the case in the answer by IV.)?

Answer (score 0):

Typically, one might make the `ViewOne` ctor parameterless, and instantiate the view model in one of two ways:

##### Code-Behind

```cs
public partial class ViewOne : ContentView
{
    public ViewOne()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = new ViewOneViewModel();
    }    
}
```

##### Xaml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentView xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:switch_views"
             x:Class="switch_views.ViewOne">
    <ContentView.BindingContext>
        <local:ViewOneViewModel />
    </ContentView.BindingContext>
    <VerticalStackLayout>
        <Label 
            Text="Welcome to .NET MAUI!"
            VerticalOptions="Center" 
            HorizontalOptions="Center" />
    </VerticalStackLayout>
</ContentView>
```

In my experience, this isn't really any different than how it worked in Xamarin.